# Referencing libraries in .NET Framework not in .NET Standard

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, dotnet-cli

I'm currently in progress of migrating a class library project to dotnet cli (RC2) from DNX (RC1). Previously, the project referenced the .NET v4.5.1 framework libraries, and the `project.json` file looks like this:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.10.0",
        "System.Web": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.DirectoryServices": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.ServiceModel": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.ServiceModel.Security": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  }
```

Now as far as I'm aware, (and I could be wrong,) unlike DNX, the new dotnet Cli doesn't support .NET 4.5.1, and instead supports .NET Standard.

So problem is, .NET Standard doesn't have all the libraries I want. What do I have to change so I can reference the .NET 4.5.1 framework libraries? I read about the imports statement, but I can't get it to work. Here is what I have so far **(updated)**:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.10.0",
        "System.Web": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.DirectoryServices": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.ServiceModel": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.ServiceModel.Security": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    },
    "netstandard1.5": {
      "imports": [ "dnxcore50", "portable-net451+win8" ]
    }
  }
```

I get errors such as this:[image: Cannot reference ParallelQuery]

I am a bit lost on what else I need to do... Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

`dotnet` supports `net451`. [Here's an example of application that has both `net451` and `netstandard`.](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/dev/src/MusicStore/project.json)

If you app was running on full desktop in RC1, there should be not problem migrating it to full desktop in RC2.

Comment: You are missing some package references for `netstandard`. `ParallelQuery` is in `System.Linq.Parallel`. Add that to the dependencies section. Here's an example: https://github.com/aspnet/Options/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Options/project.json#L24

Comment: I see, thanks. I just have 2 more errors. The System.Web is missing, and the System.Data library is missing DataRow and DataColumn definitions (but has DataTable). Any ideas?

Comment: System.Web doesn't exist for CoreCLR. You'll have to look for alternatives

Answer (score 1):

Try rolling with `netcoreapp1.0` instead of  `netstandard1.5`.

The [new RC2 templates](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/05/16/announcing-updated-web-development-tools-for-asp-net-core-rc2/) generate the following `project.json` framework element (by default):

```
"frameworks": {
  "netcoreapp1.0": {
    "imports": [
      "dotnet5.6",
      "dnxcore50",
      "portable-net45+win8"
    ]
  }
},
```

There's a little discussion about this on [GitHub](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2299). To quote richlander:

> - netstandard -> NETStandard.Library (this is expected to work on all
>     .NET
> - netstandardapp -> NETStandard.App (same as
>     NETStandard.Library + app hosts)
> - netcoreapp ->
>     Microsoft.NETCore.App (this is the .NET Core base install)

Comment: I tried this too, but it's still the same errors more or less.

Answer (score 0):

Check on the [.NET Platform Standard documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md) on GitHub.

The `netstandard1.5` target moniker targets .NET 4.6.2, which means you can't run it with .NET 4.5.1 projects.

The correct moniker to target .NET 4.5.1 and above is `netstandard1.2`.

In essence, the target moniker tells you which framework is the **lowest** supported. The lower the supported frameworks, the more of them you can target with a single moniker w/o the need of conditional preprocessor directives.

But also, the lower the target moniker, the less of the newer features won't be available (i.e. `Task.CompletedTask`).

When you need to target a older framework and want to use new functionality you have to use multiple targets, i.e. `netstandard1.2` which uses the old api and `netstandard1.3` that uses the .NET 4.6+ Api and use conditional preprocessor directives to use new Api calls in a specific target.

Comment: I *think* you've got it backwards: this question is about referencing assemblies that are in .Net 4.5.1, but are not in netstandard, like System.Web. Changing which version of netstandard you target won't help with that.